# How to take timezone into account in Calendar.current.isDateInToday?

Tags: ios, swift

I use an API that returns a date string such as `2021-05-05T23:00:00+00:00`. Then I convert this to a Swift Date object and I'm trying to use Calendar.current to check if the date is today or tomorrow.

```
    let apiDate = "2021-05-05T23:00:00+00:00";
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: apiDate)!
    
    if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(myDate) {
         print("Date is today") // this should be true
    } else if Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(myDate) {
         print("Date is tomorrow") // this is true instead
    } else {
         print("Date is not today or tomorrow")
    }
```

The problem is that `isDateInToday` should be `true`. For some reason, it adds my timezone (+3 hours) when checking if it's today and that returns `false`. How can I make it so that I get the result based on the phone local time?

Comment: As I can see, the API sends you the time in UTC, you could do something like this
`dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")`

Comment: At the time you ask the question, what is the current date in your time zone? The date you showed is very late on 5 May in the UTC time zone, but if you are in UTC + 3, it will be in 6 May in your time zone.

Comment: @dianaqqq, if you use a date formatter to convert an ISO8601 date string like the above date string into a Date, it doesn't matter what time zone you give to that date formatter. The date string includes an explicit UTC offset (0 hours).

Comment: It works if I set `UTC` to Calendar.current and dateFormatter. That was indeed the problem, I was comparing dates in different timezones. Thanks!